# Solr spellcheck configuration

Tags: solr, indexing, spell-checking

I am trying to build the spellcheck index with *IndexBasedSpellChecker*

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">text</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
</lst>
```

And I want to specify the dynamic field "*_text" as the field option:

```
<dynamicField name="*_text" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true">
```

How it can be done?

Comment: a dynamicField is actually many fields (e.g. "one_text", "two_text", etc), which one do you want to use?

Comment: I want them all to be used to build spellcheck index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy all the text fields to one field:

```
<copyField source="*_text"  dest="textSpell" />
```

and then build spellcheck index from field "textSpell"

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">textSpell</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
</lst>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful 
[Implementation of solr spellchecker](http://drupal.org/node/303937) and
[spellCheckComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent)